# Two bosons having the same state --- how do you know there are two?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bosons

So, suppose that photons have the same quantum state. How do we know that there are 'two' photons having the same state, rather than just one?

Is there a technical way to guarantee that there are two photons instead of one, or is it by stipulation?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such a thing as $n$ photons. You cannot count massless particles. You can speak of electromagnetic radiation as a whole, but not about how many photons it contains -- if you try and calculate this number, it diverges.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  the pi0 decays into two photons. one can also count photons from deexitation of atoms. we count them as signals in detectors, or dots  on film at that frequency .....

Comment: No @annav, that is not correct. The $\pi^0\to2\gamma$ transition amplitude is infrared divergent. The only way to get a finite prediction is to use Faddeev-Kulish dressed photons which are, by definition, coherent states. You cannot assign a "number of photons" to such states, because they are an average.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I can assure you that no pi0 has been found with more than two photons. If theory is unable to deal with the fact, the problem is with the mathematical model and not the pi0 experimental facts.

Comment: @annav The theory is very much able to deal with that: for reasonably high energy, the coherent states become narrow, and detectors are not able to resolve them. That doesn't mean that photon number is well-defined, just that your detector was not sensitive enough. The resolution of the detector has to be taken into account when calculating transition amplitudes of massless particles.

Comment: The "proof" is by elementary school counting. If you have two photons, then after you absorb one photon, you have one left over. That's what it means for there to be two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do we know that there are 'two' photons having the same state, rather than just one?

Take the expectation value of the number operator on that state and look at the result. If the result is two then there are two photons. If it is one then there is one.

Comment: The number operator of massless particles is ill-defined. This is the so-called infrared catastrophe.

Comment: Wrong. The number operator can be quite easily defined. See, for example, Messiah "Quantum Mechanics"; Chapter XXI (Field Quantization. Radiation Theory); Section IV (Quantum Theory of Radiation); Equation  XXI.218 (the operator representing the number of photons in a state with a given wave-vector and polarization).

Comment: Using the concept of "photon" in non-relativistic quantum mechanics is pretty inconsistent, and only yields first order approximations. In the relativistic treatment, the photon number operator is ill-defined. See Itzykson & Zuber "Quantum field theory", the discussion below eq. 1-211 (page 40).

Comment: Guy, you are just wrong. You can define a number operator for photons.

Comment: Welp... no, I'm not. Have you ever calculated a quantum-field-theoretic radiative correction?

Comment: Yes, guy. I've calculated more diagrams than you can shake a stick at. I did it a lot while I was getting my Ph.D. in physics ten years ago, how about you? Also, the OP's silly question really does not deserve all this commentary. It's a pretty bad question.

Comment: Thanks! So here's my problem. If you have two particles in your system so that the entire state lives in the tensor product space composed out of each particle, and you want to apply the number operator to that composite state, you will have to upgrade the number operator by N ⊗ 1 (or 1 ⊗ N?) to match the dimensionality. If you do this, however, it means you already know that there is more than one particle, doesn't it? 

So, the question is, if you have absolutely no idea as to how many particles there are in your system, how do you use your number operator correctly?

Comment: Best practice is not to ask a bunch of new questions in the comments to an old question. Just ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a technical way to guarantee that there are two photons instead of one, or is it by stipulation?

This is very general. If one is talking of the ambient cosmic background radiation photons , a type of photon "gas" of very low frequency, no technical way can be found since the energies are too low to measure individual photons.

Actually it is only in the creation of photons that they can be counted and verified later in detection.

Individual photons from [atomic emissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_spectrum) can be detected and their state verified  using polarizers and spectrometers. In optical frequencies their position in a spectrum can be detected as a point on a screen.

[image: emis]

individual photons will be dots filling up [the lines](http://astronomy.nmsu.edu/nicole/teaching/de04/sample02/slide04.html).

An experiment could be devised where within the $Δ(t)$ of the [Heisenberg uncertainty](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html) two photons with the same spin projection would be detected, though what this would be useful for is debatable.

If you are talking of the theoretical mathematical model representing the photons, the word "know" is irrelevant, one constructs  the model so that this is true.